# How can I make a header not apply to the first page?

Tags: header-footer

I'm using [the mla13.sty package](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/mla13), and it puts a header with my last name and page number at the upper right of every page. How can I get it to not write this header only on the first page? (And of course have page two numbered as page 2?)

Comment: `mla13` uses `fancy` pagestyle (from `fancyhdr`). Try `\thispagestyle{plain}` for the relevant page

Comment: That seems to have removed the page number from the top, but added one to the bottom. How can I remove both?

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}` is probably what he meant.

Comment: @jon: Well, actually `plain`, because it was only removing the `header`, not removing anything ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Want to answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Done so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `mla13` uses `fancyhdr` and has `\pagestyle{fancy}` as effective code, a `\thispagestyle{plain}` is sufficient for the title page, on order to remove the name information on the page header.

After that the `fancy` style will be applied again automatically.

The usual warning: Editors of papers, journals etc. or Thesis offices of universities etc. might reject such removals or additions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mla13}
\title{How to recognize trees from quite a distance away}
\firstname{Gandalf}
\lastname{Stormcrow}
\professor{Professor Dr. Arthur Gumby}
\class{How to recognize trees from quite a distance away}
\sources{numberthreethelarch.bib}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\makeheader

In a recent report by the United Nations, they found that more than 884 million people do not have access to safe drinking water \cite[e.g.][15-23]{unWater}. This number equates to more than 1 out of every 8 people, not having access to something that is so vital to human life. Knowing this fact, most must ask themselves, why the same water that we drink is used to clean our toilets and wash our lawns. The water that hundreds of millions of people would love to have, is something that we just flush down the toilet. This paper intends to examine the benefits of grey water systems, and how their use leads to increased water conservation efforts, creating more benefits then costs.

Grey water systems are a technique that aids in water conservation efforts by reusing water that doesn't need to be fully cleaned. For example, many grey water systems use the water that comes from the shower drain to water the lawn or fill the toilet. Even though this water isn't going to a water treatment plant, doesn't mean that it is not clean. Grey water systems are equipped with a filter that removes most soaps and solid objects that make their way through the drainage system \cite{planetArk}. With a private market for greywater systems developing, there are a variety of commercial systems that filter water to ``remove hair, lint, and debris, and remove pollutants, bacteria, salts'' and many more materials \cite{pacificInst2010}

\makeworkscited
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another one off the list.